# Mockar e injetar uma classe de serviço ao mesmo tempo

Tags: spring, testes, mock

Eu tenho uma classe de testes em spring que em alguns casos eu quero que ela se comporte no fluxo normal, ou seja, quando for feito um findAll() batendo no repositorio ela retorne o valor que ela seleciona do banco de dados embarcado, em outro fluxo dentro do mesmo método de teste, eu quero que quando seja feito o findAll() ele retorne um valor mockado. Necessito que seja feito dessa maneira pois quero simular dois processos concorrendo simultaneamente e testar um fluxo de négocio específico.
Eu usei um exemplo de como seria mais ou menos o mock, mas daquela maneira não funciona.

Exemplo:

```
Class Test{

  @Autowired
  private Service service;

  @Autowired
  private Repository repository;

  @Test
  public void teste(){
    service.metodo();
    when(repository.findAll()).thenReturn(null);
    service.metodo();
  }


}

class Service{

 @Autowired
 private Repository repository;

 public void metodo(){

   Entity x  =  repository.findAll();
   ....

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usar o @Autowired não vai ser mockado os valores, vai seguir o fluxo normal, no caso buscar dados na base. Tem que usar o @InjectMocks e @Mock